# How to create more than 1 alarm to a the same DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch

I have setup cloudwatch alarm for my dynamo db table. I did not find a way to setup multiple alarms to the same table. I want to set 3 alarms say at 80%, 85% and 90% threshold. Any help. Thank you.

Comment: Are you not able to click on the table in the browse view, click on 'Monitoring' and click 'Create Alarm'?

Comment: I was able to. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by going to:

**Browse view** -> **Monitoring** -> **Create Alarm**

Comment: This is what I did earlier also. But, I was able to add only one alarm. Later i figured that we could add multiple cases.